# Is there a way to get the height of the soft buttons in an xml layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm designing some Android screens using XML layouts.

One issue is that the soft buttons (the black bar with the 3 standard OS buttons [triangle, circle, rectangle, for back, home, tasks, respectively]) are **drawn over** the layout views.

Is there a way to get the height of the soft buttons **in the XML layout** (I've seen the other solutions).

To clarify, I would like to set e.g. the padding of my root view so that a footer view will be anchored positionally(x/y) just above the soft buttons.